# Css отображается в index

Tags: index, css

Есть общий файл стилей style.css. Изначально задание было скрыть превью новостей, что я и сделала, присвоив нужному классу стиль `display: none !important;`, причем по совершенно непонятной уже и мне причине, почему `!important`.

А теперь вопрос:
Данное свойство отображается в отладчике в документе index. Такого документа со стилями нет. Плагина для переработки стилей (или как там эта чушь называется) тоже нет. Дамы и господа, как найти данный стиль и исправить?!

Comment: @Anna Frank Правильно ли я понимаю, вы внесли в style.css (добавили `display: none !important`) , а теперь хотите это убрать и не можете найти данную строку в файле, но при этом в отладчике данное свойство присутствует?

Comment: Именно так. Причем, посмотрев и детально изучив код, выяснив, откуда подтягиваются его css файлы, перелопатив их, искомого стиля я так и не нашла.

Comment: @Anna Frank используете ли вы JavaScipt? Если да, то ищите в нем, должно быть что-то такое `.css("display","none !impotant")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то скорее всего изменяет JS. В эту сторону смотрите, раз нету в .css.